# Fetching datas from 3 related tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a REST-API like application with ExpressJS and MySQL.
I've got a table-structure like this:

```html
Course Table:
+----+--------+
| ID | TITLE  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | titel1 |
+----+--------+

Sections Table:
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID |  TITLE   |  CONTENT  | COURSE_ID |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Section1 | Content 1 |         1 |
|  2 | Section2 | Content 2 |         1 |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+

Content Table:

+----+--------+----------+------------+
| ID | TITLE  | CONTENT  | SECTION_ID |
+----+--------+----------+------------+
|  1 | Title1 | Content1 |          1 |
|  1 | Title2 | Content2 |          2 |
+----+--------+----------+------------+
```

```
{
id: 1,
title: title1,
sections: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: section1,
        text: Content 1,
        contents: [
            CONTENT OBJECT HERE
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: section2,
        text: Content 2,
        contents: [
            CONTENT OBJECT HERE
        ]
    }

]
```

}

I'm already getting the Course and corresponding section datas. But there is any problem with async and the map function which i doesnt get exactly..

Actually im doing this:
Fetch one course by id and then use its callback to get the sections which belongs to this course. I'm adding the sections to the course object and return in finally. This works fine.

But if i loop over each section and try to query for its contents it seems that my map() function would not wait until everything is finished..

Is there any solution for this case? I think its a really really common task to perform querys like this. I dont get why its so hard to implement this functionallity.

Comment: you would usually use graphql api language for this kinds of apis

Comment: Thanks, GraphQL seems like a very powerful technique. But if i would use this i'm in the needing to refactor the whole data-structure behind my project. Thats not worth. Is it really not common to perform such a task in Express/NodeJS ?

Comment: Node.js yes, but with the same technique as graphql recommends. GraphQL is not a language it's a pattern. However you can try writing your own workaround. Like doing a join and then having a class that formats the result of that join in your expected result.